# Use a Gnuplot variable instead of Bash Variable in a bash script + gnuplot script

Tags: bash, variables, gnuplot

Hello I want to plot smth using gnuplot in a bash script so I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
//myscript
gnuplot -persist <<-EOFMarker
        plot 'd.csv' using 3:xtic(1) with boxes notitle, 'd.csv' using 0:($3+100):3 with labels
EOFMarker
```

my problem is that the script substitute ($3+100) from bash variable (nothing+100) not from gnuplot (each value from 3rd column + 100).. how can I change the script in order to use the variable from gnuplot? thanks very much

Comment: no, it substitute $3 from bash script parameters $1,$2,$3 instead of the 3rd column from 'plot' command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work, `$3` is properly empty, consider this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set a b world
cat <<-EOF
hello $3
EOF
```

Will output `hello world`. If you want to send literal `$3` to the command you will need to escape the dollar sign:

```
#!/bin/bash
set a b world
cat <<-EOF
hello \$3
EOF
```

Comment: no, it substitute $3 from bash script parameters $1,$2,$3 instead of the 3rd column from 'plot' command

Comment: the variables like ./myscript.sh $1 $2 $3 ... do you understand me now?

Comment: @TopGamesa-Z If you want to use literal `$3` in here docs you will need to escape the dollar sign: `\$3`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `column` function, then you must not care about escaping: `$2` is a shortcut for `column(2)`.

```
gnuplot -persist <<-EOFMarker
    plot 'd.csv' using 3:xtic(1) with boxes notitle, 'd.csv' using 0:(column(3)+100):3 with labels
EOFMarker
```

BTW: when plotting labels you can use the `offset` option to specify an offset e.g. in character units:

```
gnuplot -persist <<-EOFMarker
    plot 'd.csv' u 0:3:xtic(1) w boxes t '', '' u 0:3:3 w labels offset 0, char 1
EOFMarker
```